# Unable to create a window

Tags: c++, winapi, wndproc

The RegisterClassEx function is returning a non zero value, however the CreateWindowEx function return a null.
I have read multiple answers and I seem to be following everything correctly. Could someone please review my code and tell me what is going wrong? My guess is that there is something wrong with my WndProc, but I am unable to figure out what is going wrong. I am trying to create a class that can paint windows and hence the WndProc function is a class member.

```
void windowPainter::registerWindow()
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex = { 0 };
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(wcex);
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = windowPainter::WndProc;
    wcex.hInstance = m_hInstance;
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.lpszClassName = windowClassName;

    ATOM returnValue = RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
    int lastErrorValue = GetLastError();
}

void windowPainter::createWindow()
{
    DWORD dwStyle1 = WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_LAYERED; 
    if (m_isClickThrough)
        dwStyle1 = dwStyle1 | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;

    DWORD dwStyle2 = WS_POPUP;
    RECT rc = { m_windowOriginX, m_windowOriginY, m_windowSizeX, m_windowSizeY };

    AdjustWindowRect(&rc, dwStyle1, FALSE);
    BYTE alpha_value = 255; 

    m_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(dwStyle1,windowClassName, windowTitle, dwStyle2, rc.left,
        rc.top, rc.right,
        rc.bottom,
        NULL, NULL, m_hInstance, NULL);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK windowPainter::WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    windowPainter* pThis = NULL;
    if (WM_CREATE == message)
    {
        pThis = (windowPainter*)((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->lpCreateParams;
        SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)pThis);
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    else
    {
        pThis = (windowPainter*)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
    }

    if (pThis)
        switch (message)
        {
        case WM_PAINT:
            if (pThis)
            {
                //do painting using members of pThis
            }break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            pThis->onLeftButtonClick();
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: The problem was with the variable windowClassName. I was not typecasting the value I was getting after a c_str() call to (LPCWSTR)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at these statements from your code:

```
m_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(..., NULL);
```

Here you pass `NULL` for the `lpParam` argument.

```
pThis = (windowPainter*)((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->lpCreateParams;
```

This line of code is where you read that same value. Because you passed `NULL` to `lpParam` when calling `CreateWindowEx`, you will be setting `pThis` to `NULL`.

Instead of passing `NULL` to `lpParam` when calling `CreateWindowEx` you must pass the address of the instance.

```
m_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(..., (LPVOID)this);
```

Note that these changes should not influence whether or not the call to `CreateWindowEx` succeeds or fails. For the code in the question, `pThis` being `NULL` just means that you always call the default window procedure. Which will not lead to the window creation failing. You appear to have some other problem in your code, presumably in the code that we cannot see.

Comment: That makes sense. However, now my return value from the RegisterWindowEx function is zero  (and hence the m_hWnd is still null)

Comment: The call to `RegisterWindowEx` occurs before the call to `CreateWindowEx`. How could changing one parameter to the call to `CreateWindowEx` influence the result of the call to `RegisterWindowEx`? Did you change something else?

Comment: Good point. So, i checked the values again. I am creating two instances of this class. For one of the instance, i consistently get a return value of zero, for another, it is intermittent.

Comment: @TheBlueNotebook: Show your real code, I dont see any function named "RegisterWindowEx" in your code.

Comment: OOPs, I assumed you were referring to `RegisterClassEx`.

Comment: Oops. I meant `RegisterClassEx`. Apologies.

Comment: So should I ask another question incorporating David's suggestions in my code? Because I am still unable to create a window.

Comment: This is somewhat frustrating. In the question you state, "the RegisterClassEx function is returning a non zero value". Don't give up. Debug your code. You apparently once had code that returned a non zero value. Use that code again.

Comment: Use error checking in CreateWindow(Ex)---GetLastError.

Comment: My theory: You have two instance of class, right? Probably you register class twice, so second call to RegisterClass(Ex) failed with error 1410 and due to CreateWindow(Ex) also fail.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I haven't made any changes to the code, apart from adding your suggestion. My comment that I am consistently getting a return value of zero from the `RegisterClassEx` function was wrong. It still returns a non zero value in some cases and yet in those cases the `CreateWindowEx` function returns NULL. But alright, i get it that debugging without the entire information might be frustrating, i will check again and see if I am missing anything.

Comment: I think I got the key point here. I don't think it's fair to expect us to find all the defects when we can't see all the code. I'm sorry that you don't find my answer to be useful.

Comment: @user212066 I am using a different class name for each instance. The class name is passed as a parameter in the constructor.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Just want to point out that your answer was indeed helpful. If you had no more defects to suggest in the code I posted, I can look more closely for problems in other parts of the code now. I was not as comfortable with WinProcs and hence wanted someone experienced to review, which you did.